# Vue 2 to Vue 3 migration strategy for updating codebase with many libraries?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have a large codebase using Vue 2.7.8 that relies on several external libraries targeted at Vue 2 (e.g. vue-chart-js, primevue, vuex, etc.)

I need to migrate to the latest Vue 3 version. I am aware of the [migration build](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/migration-build.html) for migrating my *own code* to Vue 3, but is there a best strategy or compatibility tool to deal with updating the external libraries to their Vue 3 versions? Or will I be forced to open a gigantic PR where every single library and their necessary tweaks to adapt to their Vue 3 version is handled there?

In an ideal world, I would somehow individually import all Vue 3 libraries version with a compatibility layer and then create a PR for each one of these, and when all this has been done, upgrade to Vue 3 and remove this made up layer.

Comment: First off, your question is *off-topic* for asking for recommendations. Secondly, there is no such migration assistant tool for Vue2 > Vue3. Thirdly, **most** libraries have not changed their internal API when migrating from Vue2 to Vue3. So, other than the way they're plugged in into Vue itself, you shouldn't expect changes in how they are consumed inside components, regardless of whether you use Options API or Composition API (which are both available in `2.7` and `3.x`). What I'm saying is that, even though it might look large in scope, the changes surface should be small.

Comment: I would start off by creating a blank Vue3, implementing the base UI framework and then adding the vue3 versions of the libraries used. Then I would start migrating the actual components one by one and solve issues as they appear. It will likely be faster and cleaner than upgrading in place, as the end result will be clean of any Vue2 boilerplate (which won't prevent the Vue3 code from running but wouldn't be necessary, either).

Comment: You can't rely on compatibility layer without a prior knowledge that a lib is compatible with it. If it uses unconventional or undocumented vue features, it won't work properly.  It's hard to say anything more specific without knowing which libs are in use. First of all make sure all of them have feature-complete V3 versions.